# Why does the characteristics method not work for boundary value problems?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, characteristics

Let us consider, for example (all though the question applies more generally) the 1D wave equation
$$ u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx}.$$
This has characteristics $x-ct = const$ and $x+ct=const$ which is readily observable by factoring the differential operator as
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} - c^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} = (\frac{\partial}{\partial t} - c\frac{\partial}{\partial x})(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} + c\frac{\partial}{\partial x}).$$
Thus, making the variable transformation $\eta = x-ct$ and $\xi=x+ct$ yields
$$
u_{\eta \xi} = 0
$$
from which we conclude that
$$ u =F(x-ct) + G(x+ct) \tag{1}\label{1}$$
for some sufficiently smooth functions $F$, $G$.

If we consider the IVP: $u(x,0) = f(x)$ and $u_t(x,0) = g(x)$ we derive [d'Alambert's solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula) from (1). However, this is the solution for a boundaryless domain and is incapable of capturing any sort of boundary values. e.g. a clamped boundary $u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0$. Yet, this is a well posed problem and solvable via separation of variables. So we can only conclude that (1) is **not** the general solution. What went wrong?

My guess is that in making the variable transformation and integrating we implicitly assume a certain global regularity which the boundary value problem does not satisfy. Any clarification or expansion on this?

Comment: You can continue the solution $u$ of the boundary value problem by odd symmetry at $x=0$ and $x=L$, giving a $2L$-periodic function. Then this is compatible with the unrestricted problem, and vice versa. The solution formula still applies, now with $F(x)=-G(-x)$ and $F(L-x)=-G(L+x)$, making both functions $2L$-periodic (with no immediate symmetry properties).

Comment: I don't follow. The solution of $u_{tt}=c^2 u_{xx}$ in $(0,L)$ with $u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0$ and $u(x,0)=f(x)$, $u_t(x,0)=g(x)$ will not be of the form (1) in general. An extension to outside the domain $(0,L)$ by odd symmetry doesn't help here.

Comment: But it works, you get mirrored waves moving in opposite directions that cancel at all times at all integer multiples of $L$.

Comment: @Lutz Your solution is $u=G(x+ct)-G(-x+ct)$ where $G$ is a $2L$-periodic function. Of course that satisfies $u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0$ but how can it possibly satisfy $u(x,0)=f(x)$ and $u_t(x,0)=g(x)$ for arbitrary $f$ and $g$?

Comment: You get $f(x)=G(x)-G(-x)$, so twice the odd part of $G$, and $g(x)=G'(x)-G'(-x)$, which integrates to twice the even part of $G$. Thus $G(x)=\frac12(\pm f(x)+\int g(x)\,dx)$ for $x\in[0,L]$ and $x\in[-L,0]$, respectively. Any integration constant cancels out in the difference.

Comment: That is simply not true. $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary! You cannot even satisfy $f(x)=G(x)-G(-x)$ unless $f$ is odd and $2L$-periodic (because $G$ is $2L$-periodic).

Comment: $f$ is only given on $[0,L]$, there can be no statement on its $2L$ periodicity. My solution formula had some missing signs, corrections now in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

No need to come back to the calculus already done leading to :
$$u(x,t)=F(x-ct)+G(x+ct) \tag 1$$
The conditions are :
$$u(x,0)=f(x)=F(x)+G(x) \tag 2$$
$$u_t(x,0)=g(x)=-cF'(x)+cG'(x) \tag 3$$
Integrating $(3)$ with $\Phi(x)=\int_0^x g(\xi)d\xi$

$\Phi(x)=-c\left(F(x)-F(0)\right)+c\left(G(x)-G(0)\right) \tag 4$

Solving $(2)$ and $(4)$ for $F$ and $G$ leads to :

$$F(x)=\frac12\left( f(x)+\frac{1}{c}\Phi(x)+F(0)-G(0)\right) \tag 5$$
$$G(x)=\frac12\left( f(x)-\frac{1}{c}\Phi(x)-F(0)+G(0)\right) \tag 6$$
Putting $(5)$ and $(6)$ into Eq.$(1)$ with respective arguments $(x-ct)$ and $(x+ct)$ leads to :

$u(x,t)=\frac12\left( f(x-ct)+\frac{1}{c}\Phi(x-ct)+F(0)-G(0)\right)+\frac12\left( f(x+ct)-\frac{1}{c}\Phi(x+ct)-F(0)+G(0)\right)$

$u(x,t)=\frac12 f(x-ct)+\frac12 f(x+ct)+\frac{1}{2c}\Phi(x-ct)-\frac{1}{2c}\Phi(x+ct) \tag 7$

$$\boxed{u(x,t)=\frac12 f(x-ct)+\frac12 f(x+ct)+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{-ct}^{x-ct} g(\xi)d\xi-\frac{1}{2c}\int_{ct}^{x+ct} g(\xi)d\xi} \tag 8$$

This solution $(8)$ satisfies the PDE $(1)$ and the conditions $u(x,0)=f(x)$ and $u_t(x,0)=g(x)$.

If more conditions are added with those new conditions (but without the preceeding ones) the equations $(1)$ remains valid but with different functions $F$ , $G$ than before according to the new conditions and diffrent equations $(2)$ and $(3)$. As a consequence at the end of a similar calculus we will obtain a different resulting equation $(8)$.

Now if we consider all the conditions together (the first ones and the new ones) the equations $(8)$ (the old and the new) are both valid. This is not contradictory and this doesn't mean that the equation $(1)$ is not the general solution. This means that the whole domain becomes fragmented in sub-domains in which different functions such as $(8)$ are respectively valid. In other words the functions $F$ and $G$ become piecewise functions.

Answer (score 0):

To get the analogue of (1) in a more general case, e.g for an inhomogeneous boundary problem, you can put
$$v = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} + c\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)u$$
so that $v$ solves the transport equation
$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} - c\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)v = 0.$$
You can solve that equation explicitly with the caracteristic method. Then, you can solve in the same way
$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t} + c\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)u = v$$
to find $u$ in terms of $v$.

Comment: I don't see how that helps. Its not really any different from what I did and still doesn't address why (1) is not the general solution.

Comment: This will give you the generalisation of (1) you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If $u$ is a solution of the boundary value problem, odd reflections on the axes $x=0$, $x=L$ and in continuation at $x=kL$ for all $k\in \Bbb Z$, generates a $2L$-periodic function. Due to the odd symmetry at the reflection axes, $u_{xx}=0$ there and $u_{tt}=0$ due to the boundary conditions, so the wave equation is satisfied on $\Bbb R$.

Thus the functions $F,G$ for the solution formula exist. The boundary conditions applied to the solution formula give $F(ct)+G(-ct)=0$ and $F(L+ct)+G(L-ct)=0$. Combining both gives
$$
G(-s)=-F(s)=-F(L+(s-L))=G(L-(s-L))=G(2L-s),
$$
so $G$ is a $2L$-periodic function and $$u(x,t)=G(x+ct)-G(-x+ct).$$

Evaluating the initial conditions gives
\begin{align}
f(x)&=G(x)-G(-x)\\
\tfrac1c g(x)&=G'(x)-G'(-x)\\
\tfrac1c\int_0^x g(s)\,ds&=G(x)+G(-x)
\end{align}
so that in combination
$$
G(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac12\Bigl(f(x)+\tfrac1c\int_0^x g(s)\,ds\Bigr), & x\in[0,L],\\
\frac12\Bigl(-f(-x)+\tfrac1c\int_0^{-x} g(s)\,ds\Bigr), & x\in[-L,0].
\end{cases}
$$
and $2L$-periodic continued outside $[-L,L]$.

Comment: This implies $f$ is odd and $2L$-periodic which we are not assuming. There are also restrictions on $g$ here which I need to think about

Comment: No, $f$ has domain $[0,L]$, this is not long enough to discuss a period $2L$. Note that now also from $g$ only values in the interval $[0,L]$ are taken.

Comment: But this produces incorrect solutions (I tested some). It also won't be differentiable for all $x\in(0,L)$ and $t>0$.

Comment: Could you give a relatively simple case where this does not work? Does this case have $f(0)=f(L)=g(0)=g(L)=0$?

Comment: Just take $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=0$. And no, we never assume that.

Comment: $G$ has discontinuities at $kL$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus $u$ has increasingly many discontinuities in $(0,L)$ as $t$ increases

Comment: Then $u(x,0)$ does not satisfy the boundary condition, at least not as $C^2$ function, you get automatically a singularity independent of what solution method you use.

Comment: Indeed, but those singularities stay at the boundary. Whereas as these ones move in.

Comment: More generally, this does not match the Fourier series solution.

Comment: A solution to a BVP that is not continuous at the boundary is rather senseless.

Comment: How so? It will be continuous for all $t>0$. It is very common practise. But if you like you can take $f(0)=f(L)=0$ and your solution has derivative discontinuities in the interior instead.

Comment: The Fourier solution has period $2L/c$ in time, the state of the initial condition periodically repeats, you can not claim continuity for $t>0$. Did you switch equations in-between, as such a smoothing property is true for the heat equation?